# Validate image uploads first and only then insert text data linked to the images in separate tables

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a form that allows me to upload images and bunch of text data into database tables. Images are connected to the text data via foreign keys.

Problem is if the form encounters a problem with uploading an image - the text data still gets inserted(if it pases its own validation).

Is there any way to first validate the images and if everything is alright then insert the text data along with images' file names into respective tables?

**controller:**

```
function addDataRow()
        {
            //Set common properties
            $data['title'] = 'Add new data row';
            $data['action'] = site_url('crud/addDataRow');
            $data['link_back'] = anchor('crud/index/', 'Back to list', array('class' => 'back'));

            //Set validation properties
            $this->_set_fields();
            $this->_set_rules();

            //Run validation
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $data['message'] = '';
            }
            else
            {
                //Get the text data from $_POST
                $data_row = array(
                    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                    'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
                    'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
                    'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                    'type' => $this->input->post('type')
                );

                //Insert text data into table
                $id = $this->crud_model->save($data_row);

                //Now move on to image processing
                //original image upload settings
                $path_to_uploads= './assets/upload';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '6000';
                $config['max_width']  = '1920';
                $config['max_height']  = '1920';
                $config['upload_path'] = $path_to_uploads;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                $arr_files = @$_FILES['thumb'];

                $_FILES = array();
                foreach(array_keys($arr_files['name']) as $h){
                    $_FILES["file_{$h}"] = array(
                        'name' => $arr_files['name'][$h],
                        'type' => $arr_files['type'][$h],
                        'tmp_name' => $arr_files['tmp_name'][$h],
                        'error' => $arr_files['error'][$h],
                        'size' => $arr_files['size'][$h]
                    );
                }

                //Initialize upload
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                foreach(array_keys($_FILES) as $h){

                    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($h)){
                        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                        //echo "<script>alert($error);</script>";
                        print($error); die;
                        //Fix this part
                    }else{
                        //Start uploading               
                        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                        $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
                        $full_file_path = $path_to_uploads.'/'.$file_name;



                        //Insert image data into table
                        $image_row = array(
                        'id_path' => $file_name,
                        'id_data_row' => $id
                        );

                        $this->crud_model->save_image($image_row);

                        if($h=='file_0'){
                            //Thumbnail config
                            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                            $config['source_image'] = $full_file_path;
                            $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                            $config['width'] = 150;
                            $config['height'] = 150;

                            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

                            $this->image_lib->resize();

                            $thumbnail_row = array(
                            'id_path' => str_replace(".", "_thumb.", $file_name),
                            'id_data_row' => $id
                            );

                            $this->crud_model->save_thumbnail($thumbnail_row);
                        }       
                    }
                }
                //Set form input name="id"
                $this->form_validation->id = $id;

                //Set user message
                $data['message'] = '<div class="success">New data row added!</div>';
            }

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/crud_edit', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
```

**model:**

```
//Add new data row
        function save($data)
        {

            $this->db->insert($this->tbl_data, $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        //Add the original image
        function save_image($data)
        {
            $this->db->insert($this->tbl_images, $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }

        //Add the thumbnail upload path and id of the row in data table to link them
        function save_thumbnail($data)
        {
            $this->db->insert($this->tbl_thumbnails, $data);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push all of your data into arrays and wait until the images are finished uploading before inserting them into the db:

```
<?php
function addDataRow()
{
    //Set common properties
    $data['title'] = 'Add new data row';
    $data['action'] = site_url('crud/addDataRow');
    $data['link_back'] = anchor('crud/index/', 'Back to list', array('class' => 'back'));

    //Set validation properties
    $this->_set_fields();
    $this->_set_rules();

    //Run validation
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data['message'] = '';
    }
    else
    {
        //Get the text data from $_POST
        $data_row = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
            'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
            'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
            'type' => $this->input->post('type')
        );



        //Now move on to image processing
        //original image upload settings
        $path_to_uploads= './assets/upload';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '6000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1920';
        $config['max_height']  = '1920';
        $config['upload_path'] = $path_to_uploads;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $arr_files = @$_FILES['thumb'];

        $_FILES = array();
        foreach(array_keys($arr_files['name']) as $h){
            $_FILES["file_{$h}"] = array(
                'name' => $arr_files['name'][$h],
                'type' => $arr_files['type'][$h],
                'tmp_name' => $arr_files['tmp_name'][$h],
                'error' => $arr_files['error'][$h],
                'size' => $arr_files['size'][$h]
            );
        }

        //Initialize upload
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        //Array for image_row data
        $image_row_array = array();

        //array to hold errors
        $error = array();

        foreach(array_keys($_FILES) as $h){

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($h)){
                $error[$h] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                //echo "<script>alert($error);</script>";
                print($error); die;
                //Fix this part
            }else{
                //Start uploading               
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
                $full_file_path = $path_to_uploads.'/'.$file_name;



                $image_row = array(
                    'id_path' => $file_name,
                    'id_data_row' => NULL,//$id isn't set yet
                );

                //push image_row data into array instead of saving to db
                $image_row_array[$h] = $image_row;

                if($h=='file_0'){
                    //Thumbnail config
                    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                    $config['source_image'] = $full_file_path;
                    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                    $config['width'] = 150;
                    $config['height'] = 150;

                    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

                    $this->image_lib->resize();

                    $thumbnail_row = array(
                    'id_path' => str_replace(".", "_thumb.", $file_name),
                    'id_data_row' => NULL,//$id isn't set yet
                    );
                }       
            }
        }


        //if $error array is empty, images uploaded Ok so add data to db

        if(count($error)==0)
        {
            //Insert text data into table
            $id = $this->crud_model->save($data_row);

            //insert image row data
            foreach($image_row_array as $k => $v)
            {
                //set id
                $image_row_array[$k]['id_data_row'] = $id;

                //if($k != 'file_0')... if you don't want file_0 in there
                $this->crud_model->save_image($image_row_array[$k]);
            }

            //set thumbnail id
            $thumbnail_row['id_data_row'] = $id;

            //insert thumbnail data
            $this->crud_model->save_thumbnail($thumbnail_row);

        }

        //Set form input name="id"
        $this->form_validation->id = $id;

        //Set user message
        $data['message'] = '<div class="success">New data row added!</div>';
    }

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/crud_edit', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: Still adds text data if images are corrupt/etc.

Comment: impossibru! maybe error is getting overwritten... say if image 2 has an error and image 3 doesn't -- error gets overwritten... I'll update the code ^

Comment: I tested it by not selecting any images at all. Then by selecting a non-image file like an .exe or .txt.

Comment: Right so the check for the error is breaking. Did you try with code that's there now?

Comment: Still inserts text. Instead of actual errors just displays "Array" now.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. Did you try emptying out the database to be certain? If the error is hit, the program `die`s, and the `if(count($error)==0)` won't be hit.

Comment: Dammit! My bad. I had a duplicate `$id = $this->crud_model->save($data_row);
` right around the beginning. Everything is in order now. Thanks and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is very simple:
First upload the images, and check for errors.
If there are any, then break the process. Otherwise insert the text data in the database.

**EDIT**
For multiple files, you do your work inside the body of `foreach(array_keys($_FILES) as $h)`.
You upload an image, if it passes, you save the image and the textual data in the database, and move to the next image.

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES) as $h){
  // Upload the image
  // Check if it succeeded
  // If yes, store the image and
  // store the textual data for it
  // proceed to next image
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Based on your last comment, you should do this (psudocode):

```
$temp_images = array(); // This array will hold the uploaded images (their path).
foreach(array_keys($_FILES) as $h){
  // Upload the image
  // Check if it succeeded
  // If yes, store it and add it to the $temp_images array and proceed to next image
  // If it did not, delete all the images in $temp_images and halt process
}
// You have all the images here
// Store the images and their textual data
```

I am sorry, I can't write actual code now. I am not at my own PC.

Comment: Yes, I can unserstand that approach with only one image being uploaded, but if you upload multiple images then you need to know the `id` of the text data before you move on to the next image in order to insert the image data into the tables with foregin key linking to text data.

Comment: One text row of data might have many images associated with it. By the logic of your pseudocode it would insert multiple rows of the same text data for each image.  Unless I'm mising something...

Comment: @user1701467 You are right. I thought that is what you want. Now: you want to upload several images and if all of them pass, then add the textual data to them. If any of the images fails to upload, you should not insert any images or textual data into the db. Am I right?

Comment: That's right. You're inserting a product information that might have multiple images of it from different angles. If image upload succeeds then insert all the uploaded images into **images** table where each image row will have a column containing the foreign key connecting to the the textual data that goes into another table **data** if image upload passes validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a simple check after upload to the DB.
If picture is not there, delete entry.
That way you do not need to change anything, just add a ckeck and delete section.